# Mathematica Random Integer Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions, mathematical-notation

Is there any way to use the RandomInteger function in Mathematica such that once an integer has been drawn, it cannot be drawn again. For example, I am looking to use the RandomInteger to draw 12 integers, between 1 & 12, such that each number is only drawn once. Thanks.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sweet, I think that will be perfect. Thank you sir.

Comment: “RandomSample[12]” is what ended up doing the trick. - SDH

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark haha. none the less, appreciate the help Mr Mark

Answer (score 0):

When applied to a list, `RandomSample` produces a random permutation.

```
RandomSample@Range[12]
```